# How to update to windows 11 after chosing "stay on windows 10 for now"

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

At some point in Windows Update I chose "stay on windows 10 for now". Now I want to upgrade to Windows 11 - what do I do ?

Comment: It is on the right hand side of the update page as 1. Check Device Specification 2. See If IT Is Ready To Install 3. Learn About Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

> At some point in Windows Update I chose "stay on windows 10 for now". Now I want to upgrade to Windows 11 - what do I do?

Download the [Windows 11 Installation Assistant](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2171764), a current Windows 11 ISO, [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2156295), or simply choose the option within Windows Update.

[image]

In the case of the Media Creation Tool and the ISO, just download the ISO, then mount the ISO within Windows and launch setup executable.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 will at some point present itself to upgrade again. You can see this in Windows Updates. You should be able to click on the Windows 11 Update.

I have done this on my Windows 11 Pro machine.

That should work.