# PC meets the min system req for Windows 11. Specific timing for when it will be offered can vary as we get it ready for you? What does this mean?

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

My laptop has said this for months?  Why won't the upgrade start?  I can't seem to find any real answer from Google.

Comment: If you go to `Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update` and click Check for Updates do you see `Feature update to Windows 11`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update to windows 11 after choosing "stay on windows 10 for now"](https://superuser.com/questions/1695887/how-to-update-to-windows-11-after-chosing-stay-on-windows-10-for-now) [I answered this exact question 6 months ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1695887/how-to-update-to-windows-11-after-chosing-stay-on-windows-10-for-now/1695889#1695889)